# how does one list all the finite sequences of a given alphabet in c#

Tags: c#, string, sequence

How could I using a simple gui consisting of a button, listbox and textbox , list all the finite sequences of a given string?. For example, list all the finite sequences of the string abcde?

Comment: Type the string into the text box, when they press the button, generate the list and put it in the listbox... is this rhetorical?

Comment: For such a small list - nothing fancy just cycle through them. Simples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you can find all code here:
[Permutations, Combinations, and Variations using C# Generics](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx)
[Permutations in C# Using Recursion](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Premutations.aspx)

And its quite simple when it comes to UI:

```
 this.listBox1.Items.Add(YourFunction(this.textBox1.Text));
```